# how to use BASE64DECODE function in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column in table (DB2 database) which contains base64 binary encoded data. I'm trying to read the data from sql developer using `BASE64DECODE` function.

I have tried below ways, but none of them seems working

```sql
Select BASE64DECODE(COLUMN_NAME) from ENCRYPTED_DATA
```

```sql
Select SYSTOOLS.BASE64DECODE(COLUMN_NAME) from ENCRYPTED_DATA
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's not working? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: I'm getting below error while executing above commands. DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=BASE64DECODE;FUNCTION, DRIVER=3.59.81

Answer (score 2):

If your Db2 platform is Linux, Unix and Windows, then there is no such a standard function.  You may create and use the following:

```
create or replace function BASE64ENCODE(b blob(1048576))
returns clob(1398102)
contains sql
deterministic 
no external action
return xmlcast(xmlquery('$d/a' passing xmldocument(xmlelement(name "a", b)) as "d") as clob(1398102))
;

create or replace function BASE64DECODE(c clob(1398102))
returns blob(1048576)
contains sql
deterministic 
no external action
return xmlcast(xmlquery('$d/a' passing xmldocument(xmlelement(name "a", c)) as "d") as blob(1048576))
;

values hex(cast(BASE64DECODE(BASE64ENCODE(blob(x'1122334455'))) as varchar(5) for bit data));

1
----------
1122334455
```

Comment: Thank you, could you please explain it. As data is inserted/read into database by application. will it cause any issue if we replace the functions ?

Comment: These are user-defined functions. You may have some issues with their recreation, if you already have some other user-defined functions with the same names and parameters only. You may create these functions and check if, for example, `BASE64DECODE` decodes your data encoded by your application (which doesn't use `BASE64ENCODE`) correctly.