# Base64 decode in db2 sql

Tags: sql, db2

Is it possible to decode a Base64 encoded string in DB2 database?

I was able to decode the string in SQL Server by casting to XML.

I am running db2 in Linux server

Comment: Which operating-system platform runs your Db2 server?  ( choose one of Z/OS,  ms-windows,  linux/unix/cloud,  i-series) .

Comment: @mao, Linux on premise server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use BASE64DECODE function in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521008/how-to-use-base64decode-function-in-db2)

Answer (score 1):

**z/OS**:

[BASE64ENCODE and BASE64DECODE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/fr/db2-for-zos/12?topic=functions-base64encode-base64decode)
Last Updated: 2022-08-23

The BASE64ENCODE and BASE64DECODE helper REST functions complete Base64 encoding or decoding of the provided text.

**Tip**: The sample HTTP user-defined functions are intended to be used within Db2 SQL applications to access remote non-Db2 REST-based services through SQL statements. Do not confuse them with Db2 native REST services, which supports using a REST-based interface to interact with Db2 data from web, mobile, and cloud applications.

[image]

The schema is DB2XML.

**text**

Specifies the text to encode or decode. For BASE64ENCODE, this argument is provided as a VARCHAR(2732) value and the function returns a Base64-encoded string. For BASE64DECODE, this argument is provided as a Base64-encoded VARCHAR(4096) value and the function returns the data as binary.

**IBMi**:

[BASE64DECODE scalar function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=overview-base64decode-scalar-function) Last Updated: 2022-05-03

The BASE64DECODE function returns a character string that has been Base64 decoded. Base64 encoding is widely used to represent binary data as a string.

[image]

The schema is SYSTOOLS.

**character-string**

A character string in CCSID 1208 that is currently Base64 encoded. The length cannot exceed 4096 characters.

The result of the function is a varying length character for bit data string that contains character-string after being Base64 decoded.

**Example**

- Decode a binary string that was originally X'1122334455'. The result is the original value.

  VALUES SYSTOOLS.BASE64DECODE('ESIzRFU=');

Comment: This answer is relevant only when the Db2-server is running on Z/OS.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- encoding 
values regexp_replace (xmlserialize (xmlelement (name "a", blob (X'1122334455')) as varchar (20)), '^<a>(.*)</a>$', '$1')
```

| 1 |
| --- |
| ESIzRFU= |

```
-- decoding (hex function use is just to get a string representation of a binary value)
values hex (xmlcast (xmltext ('ESIzRFU=') as blob (20)))
```

| 1 |
| --- |
| 1122334455 |